# Flask, Unable to import python module in same directory

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask

I just want to preface by saying I searched and found very similar questions, but unless I messed up, they did not work for me. Now to the question.

I am very new at using flask, and I am building a website using flask, and this is what my files look like:

flaskapp/ --> app.py & wordlcoud.py & templates (all three in the flaskapp directory)

I have a function in my wordlcoud.py file that I want to use in my app.py file. When I restart the server and try to navigate to my website, I only am shown 502 bad gateway, and when I delete the "import wordlcoud", my website loads fine.

Here is how my app.py file is set up:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request
import wordlcoud

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home_function():
    return render_template("home.html")

@app.route("/projects", methods=["POST", "GET"])
    if flask.request.method == "POST":

        wordlcoud.saveWC(q)

        return redirect(url_for("/output")

    else:
        return render_template("projects.html")

@app.route("/output")
def image_fxn():
    return render_template("output.html")
```

"saveWC" is the function from wordlcoud.py that I am trying to use.

I have seen to create an **init**.py file, but unless I put that in the wrong spot, that did not help at all.

Thank you in advance

Drew

Comment: You need to provide the error message from Flask. I'd also recommend to try to develop the app locally on your PC first, with no proxy in front.

Answer (score 0):

you said that when you delete this line of code the website work

```
import wordlcoud
```

well without importinh the module this must not work as well

```
wordlcoud.saveWC(q)
```

but i think that you delete that line as well, i think that the mistake is in this line not in the import line, because the the variable q not declared before,

i hope that this help

Comment: I should say this as well. Without deleteing the import statement, but deleting @app.route("/projects", methods=["POST", "GET"])
    if flask.request.method == "POST":

        wordlcoud.saveWC(q)

        return redirect(url_for("/output")

    else:
        return render_template("projects.html")

@app.route("/output")
def image_fxn():
    return render_template("output.html"), there is still an error, which leads me to believe it is not the variable q

Answer (score 0):

i think

> import `module_name`

will import whole module

|

but try to import specific function may it will solve issue

> from `module_name` import `your_function`

like this ->
**from `wordlcoud` import `saveWC`**